# How to redirect command output using os.execvp() in python

Tags: python, shell

I am invoking shell script using os.execvp() in python. my shell script has some echo statements whcih I want to redirect in file.

Here is what I am trying:

```
cmd = "/opt/rpm/rpm_upgrade.sh >& /opt/rpm/upgrader.log"
cmdline = ["/bin/sh", cmd]
os.execvp(cmdline[0], cmdline)
```

Below is the error I am getting:

```
Error:   /bin/sh: /opt/rpm/rpm_upgrade.sh >& /opt/rpm/upgrader.log: No such file or directory
```

Can any one help?

Comment: Is `/opt/Druva/rpm/rpm_upgrade.sh` and `/opt/rpm/` exist?

Comment: _No such file or directory_ - I wonder what could that possibly mean?...

Comment: @alpert: Yes. The rpm_upgrade.sh file is exist. That means /opt/rpm/ directory is also exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because you are passing this entire string as if it were the program name to execute:

```
"/opt/rpm/rpm_upgrade.sh >& /opt/rpm/upgrader.log"
```

The easy way to fix this is:

```
cmdline = ["/bin/sh", "/opt/rpm/rpm_upgrade.sh",
           ">&", "/opt/rpm/upgrader.log"]
os.execvp(cmdline[0], cmdline)
```

Now `sh` will receive three arguments rather than one.

Or you can switch to the more full-featured `subprocess` module, which lets you redirect output in Python:

```
import subprocess
with open("/opt/rpm/upgrader.log", "wb") as outfile:
    subprocess.check_call(["/opt/rpm/rpm_upgrade.sh"], shell=True,
                          stdout=outfile, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
```

Comment: It is fixing above error but problem is This  fix is not redirecting my rpm_upgrade.sh 's echo statements to /opt/rpm/upgrader.log file. It is still printing on console.

Comment: @AmarPatil: I've added perhaps a better code snippet to try to solve that problem.

Comment: When I use code 
     "process = Popen("rpm -Uvh /opt/rpm/new/client-4.1-5470.x86_64.rpm", stdout=PIPE, shell=True)
    process.communicate() "
Its hangs for long time. Anyone help me here ?